# how to explain this expression "int a=({10;});" in C language?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-extensions

During my C language practice, I face an expression and then I get it simplified as follows:

```
int a=({10;});
```

It is a legal expression since it gets past the gcc compiler. 
Please focus on this part: `({10;})`. Is anybody able to explain it? The more detailed, the better. Thanks!

Comment: I am almost positive that's a gcc extension rather than a legal piece of C code.  I'm curious to see what it is, though.

Comment: try this also `int a = [10];`

Comment: The meaning has been explained (it's a gcc extension), but it's much more clearly and portably written as `int a = 10;`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Huh? For `int a = [10];`, gcc gives me `error: expected expression before ‘[’ token`. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @KeithThompson Ok I am wrong I think `char* s = ["grijesh"];` will work so I confused. Thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: No, that's also a syntax error. (You should try it before posting.)

Comment: @KeithThompson yes you are correct I should try, Now I tried and declarations `int a = {1};` and `char *s = {"grijesh"};` works @[codepade](http://codepad.org/WOhfYE6N) my mistake used `[]` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a *statement expression*. It is a [gcc extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) and according to the documentation [6.1 Statements and Declarations in Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.

so for this piece of code:

```
int a=({10;});
```

according to these rules the value will be `10` which will be assigned to `a`.

This extension is one [many gcc extensions used in the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gcc-hacks/), although the linked article does not actually cover statement expressions, this [kernel newbies FAQ entry](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/DoWhile0) explains some of the reasoning behind using *statement expressions* in the Linux kernel.

As the *gcc* document notes compiling with the *-pedantic* option will warn you when you are using a *gcc extension*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not standard C, but an extension of GCC called [**statement expression**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). A compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an expression.

> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.

Back to in your example:

```
int a=({10;});
```

`{10;}` serves as the compound statement expression, so `a` has a value of `10`.